# Classifying animated GIFs as animation or film

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, classification

Is there any known way of differentiating between frames of real footage and animated content?  It seems like there's probably range of colors more likely to appear in a histogram for real footage, or maybe a level of color variation more likely to be in animation.

The case I'm looking at is converting GIF images to h264, so there's a max of 256 colors to work with.  I'm mostly trying to figure out when I should use the animation profile so the output is screwed up as little as possible in the transcode.

Comment: By animated content I assume you mean cartoons and the like? If so, there are many papers you can draw inspiration from, e.g., [Detecting cartoons: a case study in automatic video-genre classification](http://www.uv.es/~tzveta/invwork.pdf) or [A color-action perceptual approach to the classification of animated movies](http://alpha.imag.pub.ro/~bionescu/index_files/ICMRIonescu2010.pdf), [Detecting Cartoons: Automatic Video Genre Classification](http://www.uv.es/~tzveta/invwork.pdf)

Comment: Fantastic, thanks.  That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It's a studied problem. Here are some relevant papers:

- [Detecting cartoons: a case study in automatic video-genre classification](http://www.uv.es/~tzveta/invwork.pdf)
- [A color-action perceptual approach to the classification of animated movies](http://alpha.imag.pub.ro/~bionescu/index_files/ICMRIonescu2010.pdf)
- [Detecting Cartoons: Automatic Video Genre Classification](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5576551)